# System boot order not found after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I have managed to install Ubuntu 20.04 and when I am starting the laptop it shows system boot order not found initialising defaults and loads the OS ultimately. I had windows 7 and 10 previously installed (most probably in legacy Bios mode, I am not sure). But I used the efibootmgr in Ubuntu to check and it shows that currently, my Ubuntu is in EFI mode. I don't know how it is happening. I tried to use boot-repair to repair grub-efi, also mbr separately. But it does not help me to boot into windows anyhow. My laptop is a Lenovo z570 IdeaPad model. Is there a way to fix the boot menu so I can select whether to boot to Ubuntu or Windows? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Post link to summary report that Boot-Repair can create. But you cannot have both BIOS boot of Windows on same drive as UEFI boot of Ubuntu. Windows has to have boot flag on the primary NTFS partition with its boot files. UEFI requires boot flag on the ESP. You can only have one boot flag. Ubuntu really should not allow UEFI install onto BIOS/MBR drives with Windows. UEFI really should be on gpt partitioned drive. And Windows only boots in UEFI from gpt and only in BIOS from MBR.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which system to boot with the help of boot-repair. Installed 20.04 yesterday and had the same problem. Can you open the boot menu in BIOS?

Comment: I did that also while repairing mbr from advanced option in boot-repair to select to boot into windows 7. Still doesn't work. Same every time , bootOrder not found. Also there are like 7 entries of Ubuntu when I press f12 to select boot order before loading os.